# How can i set the bounds of the PowerPoint slide background image via interop

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

I need to use the below highlighted properties of fill in interop PowerPoint. I am trying this in C#. I found the below codes to set the slide background,

```
slide = presentation.Slides[1];

slide.FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoFalse;            

slide.Background.Fill.UserPicture("Image.jpg");
```

Now the picture is stretched and center aligned. But I could not update the bounds as highlighted in the below screenshot,

[image]

Any one of you help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

M.Ramaraj